# How to find/access /var/log/jasmin inside container

Tags: docker, jasmine

I have created by container with docker with the name `jasmin_01` using the command

`docker run -d -p 1401:1401 -p 2775:2775 -p 8990:8990 --name jasmin_01 jookies/jasmin:latest`

Now, i am trying to access log files located in /var/log/jasmin inside the container by running

`docker run -d -v /home/user/jasmin_logs:/var/log/jasmin --name jasmin_01 jookies/jasmin:latest`

and i am getting the error

> > Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/jasmin_01" is already in use by container "6bc05cf61a03b74f2b18d05378048e201e3f6ded768ddaf3f2660c39f9d76888". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

How do i solve this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It conflict cause container name `jasmin_01` is already in use. You can check it by `docker ps -a`. For resolve this problem is:

```
docker stop jasmin_01
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker run -d -v /home/user/jasmin_logs:/var/log/jasmin --name jasmin_01 jookies/jasmin:latest
```

Or easiest way is change you new container name

```
docker run -d -v /home/user/jasmin_logs:/var/log/jasmin --name jasmin_02 jookies/jasmin:latest
```

Comment: After running `docker run -d -v /home/user/jasmin_logs:/var/log/jasmin --name jasmin_02 jookies/jasmin:latest` which creates the container,  i get `Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`  when i try to telnet

Comment: Did you use firs way ? And can you show me more detail of your command telnet ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite indicative of the issue: you are trying to start a new container with the same name (jasmin01). Add a unique name, stop the existing container, or remove the `--name` so that Docker would create a unique name automatically.

Comment: I thought the 2nd command is to create a `jasmin_log` for `jasmin_01`. If that is not the case, how do i access the `jasmin_log` for `jasmin_01`

Comment: the `-v` option just  is mounting a file on your machine (host) into the container, the second command you have specified will do the mounting AND start a name container named `jasmine_01`.  if you want to access the files you can for example attach to the container `docker exec -it jasmin_01 /bin/sh`

Comment: This is a pretty typical case of needing to delete an existing container to change a `docker run` option.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run --name foo` runs *a new container* named `foo`

So, if you try to do it twice, you'll indeed get a duplicate name error, as you see

You probably want `docker exec`:

```
$ docker help exec

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container
```

e.g. `docker exec jasmine_01 cat /var/log/jasmine/jasmine.log`